# Equivalence of metrics by showing they have the same convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

> Let $d(x,y)= |x-y| +|x^2-y^2|$, prove that in $\mathbb{R}$, this metric generates the same topology as the usual topology on the reals.

I thought that one way to prove it would be picking an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)$ and seeing that it converges on $(\mathbb{R},d)$ if and only if it converges in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_u)$. I've managed to prove that if $(x_n)$ converges in $(\mathbb{R},d)$, then it converges in the $(\mathbb{R},\tau_u)$, but I'm stuck in proving the other direction.

Let $(x_n)\to \overline{x}$ in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_u)$, that is, for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N$, then
$$|x_n-\overline{x}|<\varepsilon$$

Then
$$d(x_n,\overline{x})=|x_n-\overline{x}|+|x_n^2+\overline{x}^2|<\varepsilon(1+|x_n-\overline{x}|)$$
but I don't know how to go further from here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your last line, should it be $\varepsilon(1+|x_n+\overline{x}|)$?

Comment: @C.Falcon Absolutely right. Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Pick a number $M$ such that for any $n$ we have $|x_n| < M$ and $|\bar x|<M$.

Since $x_n$ converges to $\bar x$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for any $n>N$ 
$$|x_n - \bar x| < \frac\varepsilon{2M+1}.$$
Then for $n>N$ we have
\begin{align*}d(x_n,\bar x)&=|x_n-\bar x|+|x_n^2-\bar x^2|\\
&=|x_n-\bar x|(1+|x_n+\bar x|) \\
&\le |x_n-\bar x|(1+|x_n|+|\bar x|) \\
&<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M+1} \cdot (1+M+M)\\
&=\varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: But why can we pick such number $M$? Wouldn't that assume that the sequence is bounded?

Comment: Convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: Thank you! I really need to review that stuff....

Answer (score 0):

For another approach, we can show that the bases are the same in both topologies. namely,  let $\epsilon >0,\ $fix $x_0$, and consider the basis element in the topology induced by $d$,

$B'_{\epsilon }(x_0)=\left \{ y:d(y,x_0)<\epsilon  \right \}$.

Since $d(y,x_0)=\vert y-x_0\vert (1+\vert y+x_0\vert )$, we have $\vert y-x_0\vert <d(y,x_0)$ so clearly

$\tag 1B'_{\epsilon }(x_0)\subset B_{\epsilon }(x_0)$.

For the other direction, we have

$d(y,x_0)=\vert y-x_0\vert (1+\vert y+x_0\vert )<M\vert y-x_0\vert $, where $M$ is a maximum for $1+\vert y-x_0\vert$  on the compact set $\overline B_{\epsilon /2}(x_0)$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $M\ge 1$.

Thus, if $y\in B_{\epsilon /2M}(x_0)$ then $d(y,x_0)<M\frac{\epsilon }{2M}=\frac{\epsilon }{2}<\epsilon$ so

$\tag 2B_{\epsilon /2M}(x_0)\subseteq B'_{\epsilon }(x_0)$

and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

If $|x-x_n|$ converges to $0$ then $|x^2-x_n^2|$ also converges to $0$ because for all but finitely many $n$ we have $|x-x_n|<1$, while $|x-x_n|<1\implies |x_n|<|x|+1,$ so for all but finitely many $n$ we have $$|x^2-x_n^2|=|x-x_n|\cdot |x+x_n|\leq |x-x_n|\cdot (|x|+|x_n|)\leq |x-x_n|(2|x|+1).$$ If $A_n$ and $B_n$ converge to $0$ then $A_n+B_n$ converges to $0.$  So with $A_n=|x-x_n|$ and $B_n=|x^2-x_n^2|,$ we have : If $|x-x_n|$ converges to $0$ then $d(x,x_n)$ converges to $0.$

If $a_n$ converges to $0$ with $a_n\geq b_n\geq 0$ then $b_n$ converges to $0.$ So let $a_n=d(x,x_n)$ and $b_n=|x-x_n|,$ and we have: If $d(x,x_n)$ converges to $0$ then $|x-x_n|$ converges to $0.$